# Custom Animation when back button is pressed - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I'm trying to produce a custom effect when the user presses the default back button (not custom button) of uiviewcontroller's navigation bar. I'm trying to move down a uiview to certain Y position BEFORE popping the view and let the view controller just disappear.

I tried two methods:

**Method 1**

```
    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    self.cvCell.frame = self.selectedCellFrame;
  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.75
                     animations:^{

                         [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
                         [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                         [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                     }];
    }];


}
```

**Method 2**:

```
-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{


if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]==NSNotFound) {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
       self.cvCell.frame = self.selectedCellFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
       CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
       [transition setDuration:0.75];
       [transition setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
       [transition setType:kCATransitionReveal];
       [transition setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
       [transition setDelegate:self];
       [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
     }];
  }
}
```

In both the cases the view disappears before the animation on UIView would kick in.
Any suggestions on achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Storyboards in your iOS app, you could try to implement a cusom segue animation. You can override the method `prepareForSegue:sender:` to check if the transaction should occur and the method `perform:` to bring new view controller on screen. You can then subclass `UIStoryboardSegue` and enable custom animations in there
[iOS Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomSegues/CreatingCustomSegues.html)

Comment: I'm trying to pop to viewcontroller A from B. I land on B from A using a custom segue animation ( i do use a story board). Should I have to create another custom segue to pop this view controller?

Comment: Yes, it might also take reconfiguring the "back" button if it is going back automatically. After looking into it `prepareForSegue:sender:` only works in the forward direction, to move in the backwards direction use `prepareForUnwind:sender:` More information here:
[http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/12/01/program-ios-unwind-segue/](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/12/01/program-ios-unwind-segue/)